# Hiding Google Translate Box on Certain Pages

Tags: google-translate

I would like the website visitor to be able to select the language on certain pages using the code I am provided which all works fine:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,bg,cs,da,de,el,en,eo,es,fi,fr,hr,hu,id,it,ja,ko,lt,lv,nl,no,pl,pt,ro,ru,sv,th,tl,tr,uk,vi,zh-CN,zh-TW', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'MY_GOOGLE_ID'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

However, I would like the code above with regards to selecting the language only displayed on certain pages.

What code would I have to put on the pages where it should continue to translate but where the Google translate select box does not display?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is add a class to your `<body>` like so `<body class="page-1">` for each page(each page different class), then style it with CSS to display:none;

```
.page-1 #google_translate_element {
display: none;
}
```